# How to store date in IST format in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

Unable to store date in IST format in mongo DB

Currently storing date in UTC format during every operations i have to change it into IST format using timezone feature provided by mongo

Comment: MongoDB stores date as UTC times - always and only, there is no possibility to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that. MongoDB will always save time in UTC.

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and converts any local time
> representations into this form. Applications that must operate or
> report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone
> alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in
> their application logic.

You can check the [official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/model-iot-data/#time-representations-in-mongodb) for more info.